# Add 24 hours to timestamp in R and exit loop

Tags: r, datetime, loops, time

Given

```
launchTime = Sys.timeDate(FinCenter = "America/Los_Angeles")
```

`launchTime` looks like:

```
America/Los_Angeles
[1] [2013-06-26 12:52:28]
```

I would like to add 24 hours to tStamp and call it `exitTime`.

Now at `launchTime` I start an R script which has a loop, that runs for say 7 days.

What would be a good way to put in a condition or few lines code that allows for exiting from the loop when the real time reaches `exitTime`?

Now I would like the condition to check till the accuracy of the day, hour and minute level. Not at the seconds level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set something like: `exitTime <- as.numeric(Sys.time()+(60*60*24))` (to get one day from the present) second. Then include a conditional in your loop like:

```
if(as.numeric(Sys.time()) > exitTime)
    break
```

I don't follow your bit about precision.

Comment: but the > than condition accounts for it.